# Pierdo datos en la URL al enviar por GET

Tags: php, url

Estoy enviando datos con el metodo get mediante la url. dentro de las primeras 2 paginas se envian todos los datos pero al llegar a la tercera un dato se envia a medias el cual es una direccion : macul #1213 y al momento de llegar a la siguiente pagina solo aparece Macul y los numeros se pierden y cuando llamo a comuna que tambien lo envio por url y en la pagina anterior si aparece , en la siguiente solo desaparece. dejo codigo e imagenes

pagina 1

```
<?php

//TRAIGO LOS DATOS DESDE EL URL Y LOS COLOCO DENTRO DE VARIABLES
if (isset($_GET['documento_seleccionado']) && isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
  $documento_seleccionado = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];
  $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
}
?>

<?php


echo '<td><a href="mostrar_horas.php?documento_seleccionado='.$documento_seleccionado .'&nombre='.$nombre . '&nombrenot=' . $fila['nombre'] . '&notaria_seleccionada=' . $fila['id'] . '&direccion='. $fila['direccion'] . '&comuna='. $fila['comuna'] . '" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><h6>Continuar</h6></a></td>';
```

pagina 2

```
<?php

//TRAIGO LOS DATOS DESDE EL URL Y LOS COLOCO DENTRO DE VARIABLES
if (isset($_GET['documento_seleccionado']) && isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
  $documento_seleccionado = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];
  $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
  $notaria_seleccionada = $_GET['notaria_seleccionada'];
  $nombrenot = $_GET['nombrenot'];
  $direccion = $_GET['direccion'];
  $comuna = $_GET['comuna'];
}
?>


</tr><a href="completar_tramite.php?documento_seleccionado=<?php echo $documento_seleccionado; ?>&nombre=<?php echo $nombre; ?>&nombrenot=<?php echo $nombrenot; ?>&direccion=<?php echo $direccion; ?>&comuna=<?php echo $comuna; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Continuar</a>
```

pagina 3

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['documento_seleccionado']) && isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
  $documento_seleccionado = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];
  $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
  $notaria_seleccionada = $_GET['notaria_seleccionada'];
  $nombrenot = $_GET['nombrenot'];
  $direccion = $_GET['direccion'];
  $comuna = $_GET['comuna'];
}
?>

</div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Documento seleccionado: <?php echo $nombre ?>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Notaria: <?php echo $nombrenot; ?>, <?php echo $direccion; ?> , <?php echo $comuna; ?> </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">19 de Enero de 2023 a las: 14:00 (podrás reagendar si lo necesitas)</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

pagina 1

[image: pagina 1]
pagina 2

[image: pagina 2]
pagina 3

[image: pagina 3]

ERROR

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo voy a responder fácil, he replicado todo tu escenario y solo tienes dos cosas.

La primera es que en **mostrar_horas** no estas mandando la variable **notaria_seleccionada** y eso te genera un error en la pagina de **completar_tramite**.

Con la dirección lo que hace que tu url tenga error es el símbolo numeral **#**. Así que debes escapar ese símbolo de la siguiente forma:

```
// Cuando lo vas a mandar usas urlencode
echo '<td><a href="mostrar_horas.php?documento_seleccionado='.$documento_seleccionado .'&nombre='.$nombre . '&nombrenot=' . $fila['nombre'] . '&notaria_seleccionada=' . $fila['id'] . '&direccion='. urlencode($fila['direccion']) . '&comuna='. $fila['comuna'] . '" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><h6>Continuar</h6></a></td>';

// Cuando lo vas a recibir usas urldecode
$direccion = urldecode(($_GET['direccion']));
```

Eso para todos los archivos y listo.

Ojo, se que estas iniciando pero todo esto lo deberías "sanitizar" de otra forma, pero mientras investigas como hacerlo de la mejor manera y con las mejores practicas, con lo que te he dicho puedes iniciar.

Resultado (con error de la variable que no envías)
[image: Resultado]

Comment: muchas gracias tu respuesta me ayudo bastante y pude resolver mi consulta. por otro lado me gustaría saber como poder "sanitizar" mi codigo ya que quiero realizar buenas practicas desde un inicio

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si resolvió tu problema. Con lo otro, con solo poner **sanitizar datos en php** tienes una infinidad de recursos para aprender todo lo que necesites...