# parametro get en php

Tags: php, mysql, get

tengo una consulta que recoge el parametro de la url
pero el error es que si yo pongo por ejemplo (en la url) **puesto=c++**

y recupero el dato para la consulta no me agarra el dato, pero si le coloco algun nombre sin caracteres especiales como:

**puesto=puesto de trabajo programador**

si lo agarra para la consulta

entonces pienso que lo que esta mal es que no recupera los caracteres especiales de la url
adjunto codigo de la recuperacion de datos php

```
//obtener el dato de puesto de la url
$id_empresa = $_SESSION['id_empresa'];
$puesto = $_REQUEST['puesto'];


//consultar la oferta

$quieryOferta = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM oferta_trabajo WHERE puesto = '$puesto' AND fk_id_usuario_empresa = '$id_empresa' ");
$recorrerOferta = mysqli_fetch_array($quieryOferta);
```

ya intente convertir el parametro en string antes de mandarlo por url pero igual no me devuelve nada en la consulta porque no agarra los caracteres especiales de la url

y si le hago un echo a **puesto=c++**
solo me debuelve **c**

lo que significa que no me esta agarrando el '++'

y lo mismo pasa con el '#'

Comment: Tenes que pasar los datos en formato URL para que después los puedas recuperar correctamente. ¿Podrías mostrar el código donde armas las URLs?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: En la URL el signo + el sistema lo traduce como un espacio. Tendrás que hacer un [encoding de la url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Percent-encoding) para pasarlo por esa vía. Otras opciones, pasarlo vía POST

Comment: probe con el parametro urlencode, ahora me agarra bien el parametro, pero si tiene algun espacio en blanco tambien me aparece con un '+'

adjunto codigo de como paso el parametro por url

-----
<a href="../VEROFERTACONASPIRANTES/verOfertasConAspirantes.php?puesto=<?php echo urldecode($recorrerOfertaEmpresa['puesto']) ?>" class="verDetalles">Ver detalles...</a>

--------
y asi lo recupero

------
$puesto = urlencode($_REQUEST['puesto']);

-----

Comment: Usa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/587767/pierdo-datos-en-la-url-al-enviar-por-get/587781#587781) para guiarte.

Answer (score 1):

lo pude resolver, el problema era que al enviar el parametro como

```
urlencode($fila['puesto'])
```

en la url me lo mostraba asi: `puesto=c%2B%2B+google`

y si lo recuperaba con un

```
$puesto = urldecode(($_REQUEST['puesto']));
```

no me lo devolvia bien, entonces intente obtener el dato sin codificar, osea asi

```
$puesto = $_REQUEST['puesto'];
```

lo cual si me da el parametro sanitizado

ejemplo de lo que sucede en el codigo

//envia el parametro por ulr

```
urlencode($fila['puesto'])
```

// parametro mostrado en url: `puesto=c%2B%2B+google`

//obtener el parametro por request

```
$puesto = $_REQUEST['puesto'];
```

//parametro obtenido

```
echo $puesto >>>> c++ google
```